# Convergence of Sequence of Approx Solutions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow K$ be continuous and let $y\in K\backslash (ranS)$. Let $\lbrace x_n\rbrace_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a sequence of approximated solutions of $Sz=y$ i.e $\|Sx_n-y\| \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Show that $\|x_n\| \rightarrow \infty$.

Here's my outline of proof:
I will use contradiction stating that $\|x_n\|$ is a bounded sequence. Then I will use the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem to show its subsequence has a limit. Thus $Sx_n\rightarrow Sx$.

Can anyone help me with the proof? I don't know what to insert with my outline and oh is it even right? If yes, where would the contradiction appear?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is $ranS$? Also what do you assume about $K$?

Comment: Oh yeah right $ranS$ means the range of $S$ and $K$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem right to me. If the equation has a solution, i.e a $z$ such that $S(z)=y$, then $x_n=z$ is an approximated solution and it has a finite norm.

Comment: What I wrote? Do you mean the problem or my outline? The problem was given to us. If it's my outline would you like to fill in the blanks? Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to be a bit more careful. Closed and bounded sets need not be compact in infinite dimensional Hilbert space. However, because the domain of $S$ has finite dimension, so does the range of $S$, and there the Heine-Borel property does hold.

So, suppose $\|x_n\|\not\to\infty$. Passing to a subsequence, $\|x_n\|$ is bounded. Because $S$ is bounded, the sequence $Sx_n$ is bounded in a finite dimensional subspace of $K$. So, it has a subsequence that converges to a point (*in the range*). Do you see how to finish the argument?

EDIT:

We have a subsequence $(Sx_{n_k})_k$ and a point $z$ in the range such that $Sx_{n_k}\to z$. But $(Sx_{n_k})_k$ also converges to $y$, so $y=z$, so $y$ is in the range, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Would you like to fill in my blanks? Hehe.

Comment: Please see my edit. Does that help?

Comment: Oh so the contradiction happens when $y\in ranS$?

Comment: Yes, because you were operating under the assumption that $y\not\in\text{ran}(S)$.

Comment: Um. Wait. I'm a bit confused. How is $z$ in the range?

Comment: Finite-dimensional subspaces are closed

Comment: So you just let point $z$ to be the limit of $Sx_{n_k}$? What I did is that $Sx_{n_k} \rightarrow Sx_n$, is this right? I just thought it's clearer that it is indeed in ran$S$.

Comment: Writing $Sx_{n_k}\to Sx_n$ doesn’t really make sense, what is $n$? You know that $z$ is $S$ of something, but you have no idea what that something is.

Comment: Because I thought since $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x_n$. That is why. Hehe.